# Javascript, adding multiple arrays to an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

What is the best way to consolidate this code? As it is, it works perfectly, but it needs to go up to maybe 40-50 items long, so it needs to be shortened dramatically, (I assume, with a for loop).

I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to Javascript, and trying to add arrays to an array with a loop is confusing me immensely.

The "vac1.", "vac2." ...etc, variables are used later on in the code to add pointers onto a Google Maps map.

```
var x = count.count; // x = a value that changes (between 1 & 50)

if(x == 1){
    locations = [
        [vac1.vacancy_title, vac1.vacancy_latlng, vac1.vacancy_url, vac1.vacancy_location]
    ];
}
if(x == 2){
    locations = [
        [vac1.vacancy_title, vac1.vacancy_latlng, vac1.vacancy_url, vac1.vacancy_location],
        [vac2.vacancy_title, vac2.vacancy_latlng, vac2.vacancy_url, vac2.vacancy_location]
    ];
}
if(x == 3){
locations = [
    [vac1.vacancy_title, vac1.vacancy_latlng, vac1.vacancy_url, vac1.vacancy_location],
    [vac2.vacancy_title, vac2.vacancy_latlng, vac2.vacancy_url, vac2.vacancy_location],
    [vac3.vacancy_title, vac3.vacancy_latlng, vac3.vacancy_url, vac3.vacancy_location]
];
}

...etc etc...
```

I have tried using a for loop, but it doesn't work and I have no idea if I am anywhere close to figuring out how to do it correctly.

```
var x = count.count;
locations = [];
array = [];

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    array = [vac[i].vacancy_title, vac[i].vacancy_latlng, vac[i].vacancy_url, vac[i].vacancy_location];
    locations.push(array);
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do `vac[i]` as there is no array called `vac`.

Comment: choose a different data structure of the pattern `vac1`. use an array for it.

Comment: Where does the `vac*` variables come from.

Comment: Check the answer it is what you need

Comment: what is the content of `count`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I am using "wp_localize_script" to bring the vac variable across to the javascript file.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am using "wp_localize_script" to set x as the number of items in the array (count.count).

Comment: what is the content of `count`?

Comment: where do you get the variables `vac1`, ... from?

Comment: @NinaScholz I am also getting the vac[x] variables by using the wp_localize_script from inside a WordPress php file.

wp_localize_script('file_name', 'vac'.$x, $array[$x]);

Comment: where do you get the count from?

Comment: @NinaScholz count also comes from the wp_localize script. It basically just sets x to the total number of items needed in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider them as a string:

```js
var x = 5;
locations = [];
array = [];

for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    array = ['vac'+i+'.vacancy_title', 'vac'+i+'.vacancy_latlng', 'vac'+i+'.vacancy_url', 'vac'+i+'.vacancy_location'];
    locations.push(array);
}

console.log(locations);
```

Comment: The array will be `["vac1.vacancy_title", "vac2.vacancy_title", ...]` which are strings.

Comment: That is what the OP wants in the array

Comment: No, he wants the vacancy titles, not the string `vac.vacancy_title`. He wants the value of `vac.vacancy_title`, example, `Vacancy Foo` or `Vacancy Bar`.

Comment: I don't think so. Look at the way he has mentioned `if(x == 1)` , `if(x == 2)` and `if(x == 3)`

Comment: Yes, that's just to know how many vacancies to add to the array, so when `x == 3` add `3` vacancies, if `x == n` add `n` vacancies.

Comment: Then the code inside the for loop should work for OP . There should not be any problem. Then why this question was posted

Comment: I know @ibrahimmahrir but the OP expects that output

Comment: @AKA This question was posted to avoid repetition of the same code, read it again.

Comment: @MrGeek then what is the problem with the for loop posted in question?

Comment: @AKA The problem with the loop is that it tries to access to array elements, such as `vac[1]` or `vac[2]`, but there is no array called `vac`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array `vac` and use your previous code :

```
var x = count.count;
locations = [],
array = [],
vac = [ /* vac1, vac2, ...., vacn */ ];

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    array = [vac[i].vacancy_title, vac[i].vacancy_latlng, vac[i].vacancy_url, vac[i].vacancy_location];
    locations.push(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the `vac*` elements in an array and then use `slice` to cut out as many as you want, then use `map` to generate the result `array`:

```
var vacs = [vac1, vac2 /*, ...*/];                       // group the vacs into one single array

var x = count.count;                                     // x is the number of vacs to generate

var locations = vacs.slice(0, x).map(function(vac) {        // slice (cut out) x elements from the arrays vacs then map the cut-out array into your result array 
    return [vac.vacancy_title, vac.vacancy_latlng, vac.vacancy_url, vac.vacancy_location];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval` for the variable name and build an new array with another array for the wanted keys.

Basically you should reorganize yor program to use a solution without `eval`. An array could help. It is made for iteration.

```
var x = count.count,
    i,
    keys = ['vacancy_title', 'vacancy_latlng', 'vacancy_url', 'vacancy_location'],
    locations = [];
    object;

for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    object = eval('vac' + i);
    locations.push(keys.map(function (k) { return object[k]; }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because any global variable is a property of the global object :

```
var vac1 = "whatever";
console.lof(window.vac1); // => logs "whatever"
console.lof(window["vac1"]); // => accessed as an array, logs "whatever" too
```

You could use the global object and access it as an array to look for your vac1, vac2, vac3 variables :

```
var x = count.count, i;
locations = [],
array = [],
var globalObject = window; // or whatever the global object is for you
var vac; // this will be used to store your vac1, vac2, etc.

for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    vac = globalObject["vac"+i]; // the "vac" + i variable read from the global object 
    if (vac !== undefined) {
        array = [vac.vacancy_title, vac.vacancy_latlng, vac.vacancy_url, vac.vacancy_location];
        locations.push(array);
    }
}
```